# Is there a web3 api written in golang to interact with Eth nodes?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, golang

I'm looking for a library that can easily interact with Ethereum nodes that is similar to Web3.js.

go-ethereum is written entirely in go so I would of thought I could write scripts pretty easily.

Comment: Hi there. https://goethereumbook.org/en/ might be worth looking at.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eth client that already include in the code base of go-ethereum to interactive with chain like web3

You can reference to my sample repo below

https://github.com/hadv/go-ethclient/blob/master/main.go

INFURA also develop their own lib, PTAL

https://github.com/INFURA/go-ethlibs